# What button is clicked in a dynamic number of buttons

Tags: php

I have a database that contains an autoincrement id, the location and the date's trip. With this code I can show on display the result of my query.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "trip");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE location = '$location'");

echo "<br/><h3>"."Result, I found " .$result->num_rows. " results.". "</h3><br/>";


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["location"]."</td><td>".$row["date"]."</td><td>".' <button type="submit" value="reserve"/>'. "</td></tr>";
}
```

How can I know which button the user click to reserve his trip?

Comment: use `function` in `onclick`

Comment: is date and location both have unique values?

Comment: How are you processing after the user clicks? If you are POSTing to another page you can avoid JS and pass a value with the button.
If this is solely frontend, use .click and capture the value with this. (@Alive to Die gave you a jquery example below)

Comment: @Dharman it's not a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).val()); // do anything what you want

});
```

Sample snippet:-

```js
$('button').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).val()); // do anything what you want
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>pahse 7, mohali</td>
    <td>04/06/2019</td>
    <td><button value="Click Me!">Click Me</button></td>
  </tr>
```

Note:- instead of `submit` button use `input type="button"`, as submit button used to submit form normally.

Comment: How can I write, in the alert, a message like this: "You reserved a trip for $name_ of_the_trip the $date"?

Comment: @Zatarra97  you have to fist send that row data to php code so that some query will run and do proper changes.after that return success or failure of query execution. if success alert trip reversed otherwise alert trip cancellation error. and then try to debug and find out error and rectify them.

Comment: Can you help me with this? i never use Jquery, i have to put this code in a new page?

Comment: @Zatarra97  for that you have to ask a new question. your current question is already answered. Ask a new question with proper input data, your code effort, explanation of your problem and expected outcome also

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery, or JavaScript at all, unless you want to submit the form with AJAX, which you haven't mentioned. You just need to fix your HTML.

`<button>` is not an empty element; it needs a closing tag. The text on the button goes between the tags. Give the button a name and assign the row id as its value.

```
$button = "<button type='submit' name='id' value='$row[id]'>Reserve</button>";
```

Then you can get the id of the clicked button from `$_POST['id']` in the PHP script that handles the form submit.

---

Also, with this code

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE location = '$location'");
```

there is no way SQL injection is not a problem, regardless of what you've done on the client side. Client side validation is trivial to bypass. [You need to use a prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

To get particular row information use data attribute in your button and then get that information

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "trip");
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE location = '$location'");

echo "<br/><h3>"."Result, I found " .$result->num_rows. " results.". "</h3><br/>";


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["location"]."</td><td>".$row["date"]."</td><td><button type='button' data-bind='".$row["location"]." - ".$row["date"]."' value='reserve'/></td></tr>";

}
```

Use Jquery to get that information

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
  var info=$(this).attr('data-bind');
    alert(info); 

});
```

Comment: that is not the correct way to do that. what happen if table have 20 or more `<td>` in a row. As well as your code required an additional split based on `-` too.

Comment: I never used Jquery, I have to create a new file and put this code in?

Comment: @AlivetoDie my table contain only 4 <td> in a row