# Use Ajax and PHP

Tags: jquery

I have found in this question this code: [What button is clicked in a dynamic number of buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56441993/what-button-is-clicked-in-a-dynamic-number-of-buttons)

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    alert($(this).val()); // do anything what you want
});
```

AND

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>pahse 7, mohali</td>
    <td>04/06/2019</td>
    <td><button value="Click Me!">Click Me</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I think that the first code is PHP and second AJAX.

How can I do to make this work? When I copy this code in the same page I've got this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: No part of this is PHP or Ajax. I removed those tags and added the jquery tag.

Comment: Neither is what you think it is.

Comment: So what I have to do to use this code with PHP?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20150474/2191572 for an AJAX example.

Answer (score 1):

This line includes the jQuery library.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

None of those that you sent is an Ajax!

If you're getting any server errors it's related to your PHP files!

You need to make an API to contact with your server.

Create a PHP file and paste these lines in that file

```
$posts = [
  ['title' => 'Post Title', 'body' => 'Post Body!']
];
print_r(json_encode($posts));
```

Here is an example of a free API, If you want to use the above code replace URL with the URL of PHP file.

```js
$("#ajax-trigger").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result){
      $.each(result,function(index, postObj){
        $('div').append("<h2>" + postObj.title + "</h2><p>" + postObj.body + "</p>");
      });
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log(error.status);
    },
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('#status').html('<strong>Loading...</strong>');
    },
    complete: function(){
      $('#status').empty();
    },
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
        alert( "page not found" );
      }
    },
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body bgcolor='#f9f9f9'>
<p id="status" style="position:absolute; left:45%; top:30%; font-size:35px;"></p>

<div class='p-3'>
<button id='ajax-trigger' class='btn btn-success d-block w-75 mx-auto my-3'>Click Here</button>
</div>

</body>
```